# Ansible module that allows git init and avoids ansible-lint warning

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible project that involves the following task:

```
- name: Perform a git init in source folder
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: git init
    chdir: ~/Projects/kernel/src
    creates: ~/kernel/src/.git
```

However ansible-lint does not like this:

```
WARNING  Listing 1 violation(s) that are fatal
command-instead-of-module: git used in place of git module (warning)
```

I have tried using the ansible.builtin.git module but I can't seem to find a way to make it just do an init.

Any suggestions?

Stephen

I was trying to write an Ansible task that essentially performs a `git init` in a folder without ansible-lint complaining. But I can't seen to find an ansible-lint clean way of doing this.

Comment: the ansible-lint message is informing that instead of using the Ansible module, command is used; in this case, the error message is correct as that is the case. What was the error message when the git module was used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible: how to init git bare repository and clone it to the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204455/ansible-how-to-init-git-bare-repository-and-clone-it-to-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 1):

Ansible’s git module requires repository as mandatory parameter, create a remote repository before initialising the local repo.

Task with ansible’s built in git would look like

```
- name: Perform git init
  git: 
    repo: https://github.com/username/repo.git
    dest: /home/user/Projects/kernel/repo.git
    bare: yes
    update: no
```

Also prefer absolute path over relative.

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo. Unforuntely this generates a new ansible-lint error as follows:

```latest[git]: Result of the command may vary on subsequent runs.
~/Projects/batesste-ansible/roles/kernel_setup/tasks/main.yml:46 Task/Handler: Perform a git init in source folder
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip false positives from ansible-lint, using [skipping rules](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/usage/#false-positives-skipping-rules)

```
- name: Perform a git init in source folder
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: git init # noqa command-instead-of-module
    chdir: ~/Projects/kernel/src
    creates: ~/kernel/src/.git
```

Comment: Thanks @HiroCereal. I have that skip in my ansible-lint config but I consider that a work-around and not a proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue and from the [ansible-lint docs](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/latest/#correct-code) it seems that the linter requires you to explicitly mention the branch name you want to pull.

An example that will not cause a linting error:

```
---
- name: Example for safe git clone
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Clone emacs
      ansible.builtin.git:
        repo: git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git
        version: master # <-- this will not cause a linting error
```